# Compare the Text box value with database value and update into different table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using entity framework 4. I need to update 2 different tables. First, need to compare the text box entered the value with database value. If the textbox entered value does not exist or not same as database value then update the 2 different tables. table 1 consists of user details and table 2 contain modified detail. 
Suppose I update the Phone number field then the updated data should save in user details table as well as the modified filed details should save in log file like who modified, date and the filed name.

UserLog Table

[image: UserLog Table]

View :

```html
@model ApiSample.Models.TestData
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <form>
        <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
        
             <p>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address) @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address)</p>
             <p>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber) @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)</p>
     <button type="submit" title="Submit">Upload Image</button>    
    </form>
}
```

Model :

```
    public partial class TestData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

    public partial class UserLog
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedFiledName{ get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :

// I don't know can it be done this way.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About(TestData testdata, UserLog log)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // insert into Userlog table
            var inputUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["INPUT_USER"].ToString().ToLower();
            var usr = _db.UserLogs.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
            string date = DateTime.Now;
            usr.UserName = inputUser;
            usr.ModifiedFiledName = PhoneNumber;
            usr.Date = date;

            // update TestData table
            _db.TestDatas.Add(testdata);
            _db.Entry(testdata).State = EntityState.Added;
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("About");
    }
```

How do I update the 2 tables in the same controller class?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do here. Why do you have the foreach in the view inside a form when you do not submit anything? (No submit button). I quess you should create a kind of service for your UserLog-saving mechanism that you can call from all other controllers.

Comment: Sorry I added wrong view code. I have edited now.

Comment: Whenever I user goes to about page updates phone number or address I need to save the updated data into testdata table and also i want to add modified date, username and modified field into userlog table. userlog table to track which user modified the data in about page.

Comment: Something still wrong here. It seems that you are trying to submit a TestData model, but you are reciving a UserLog class in the About method. And where does "Email" int the About-method come from? Does this even compile?

Comment: Sorry I missed to edit the controller. I am not sure how do I update the 2 different tables in a single controller. when I remove the userlog code inside the controller it works. BUt not sure how do I add the userlog table also inside about controller class and update both userlog and testdata tables at the same time

Comment: `How do I update the 2 tables in the same controller class?` -- Well, you already know the logic. If `db.<Entity>.Any(e => /* your criteria here*/);` then you'd pivot off that and use `db.<OtherEntity>.Add(<model here>)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult About(TestData testdata) //No need for UserLog model here
{


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // insert into Userlog table
        var inputUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["INPUT_USER"].ToString().ToLower();
        var usr = _db.UserLogs.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
        string date = DateTime.Now;
        usr.UserName = inputUser;
        usr.ModifiedFiledName = PhoneNumber;
        usr.Date = date;

        _db.UserLogs.Add(usr);
        _db.Entry(usr).State = EntityState.Added;

        // update TestData table
        _db.TestDatas.Add(testdata);
        _db.Entry(testdata).State = EntityState.Added;

        //Save both tables
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("About");
}
```